# Installing a Kohler shower faucet

Tags: shower, faucet

My shower currently has a Delta shower faucet (https://www.manualslib.com/manual/37410/Delta-1700-Series.html).

I am planning to replace it with a kohler rubicon shower faucet. (http://www.us.kohler.com/webassets/kpna/catalog/pdf/en/1110626_2.pdf)

I want to see if i can avoid removing the existing Delta valve. Is it possible to use the existing valve for the Kohler ?

Comment: Wow that is confusing, reread what you asked. Why would you replace your valve but keep the original valve? Are there some parts like manifolds you want to keep? At this point I would say No. Diferent brands have diferent body styles if you are talking about the guts of the faucet.

Comment: There is no access to the valve from behind the shower, so replacing the valve would entail putting a hole in the tile and shower, which is why i wanted to keep the valve.

Comment: @Ed Beal is correct. Trim, accessories, etc. are specific and unique to manufacturer and different brands and models are not interchangeable. Like a car, the body of a Jaguar will not fit on the chassis of a Ford.

Comment: What is wrong with the existing Delta shower valve?

Comment: NO. If you want a different "look" or the existing shower hardware is damaged or stained, you can buy replacement DELTA hardware, otherwise entails a fairly complicated process that should be done by a professional.